# SIM900 to Raspberry

Tags: raspbian, python, serial, gsm

I've recently bought SIM900 with [this module](http://www.propox.com/products/t_279.html?lang=en).
Connected it to Raspberry Pi - GND, 5V, RX-TX, TX-RX.
I'm using following code to test it (found on web):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import argparse
from datetime import datetime
import logging
from serial import Serial
from sim900 import Sim900, SMSReader
from time import sleep


LOG_FILE = 'sensor.log'
LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
LOG_FORMAT = '%(levelname)s - %(message)s'


def main():  
    # Parse command line arguments
    #
    # The default settings will work well for the pcDuino. If you
    # are using a laptop or Raspberry Pi, then you will need to set
    # the serial baud rate to 9600 and make sure the shield is running at 
    # 4800. An alternative is to increase buffer size in the Arduino SoftwareSerial
    # library.
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run SMS Data Logger.')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', help='Serial port', default='/dev/ttyAMA0')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--baudrate', type=int, help='Baudrate of Sim900 GSM shield', default=9600)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    port = args.port
    baudrate = args.baudrate


    # Setup logger
    logging.basicConfig(level=LOG_LEVEL, format=LOG_FORMAT)

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    file_log_handler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE)
    logger.addHandler(file_log_handler)

    formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)
    file_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # Creates a serial connection to Sim900 shield
    sim900 = Sim900(Serial(port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=0), delay=0.5)

    # Listens for incoming SMS
    reader = SMSReader(sim900)

    # For non-pcDuino devices, there looks to be a delay before commands
    # are sent and read correctly. Waiting two seconds seems to work.
    print "Initializing serial connection..."
    sleep(2)

    print ""
    print "Sim900 SMS Data Reader"
    print "----------------------"
    print ""
    print "Press CTRL+C to stop the program."
    print ""

    print reader.init_reader()

    while True:
        text_msg = reader.listen()
        if text_msg is not None:
            logger.info("Text message received at {0}.".format(datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")))
            logger.info(text_msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Here is sim900.py](http://pastebin.com/hDMq7vYE)

According to init_reader method, it should return "Sim900 response to commands." when connected properly, but it returns "No active connection".
Am I missing something with connection or my code? The NET LED should turn on?
I just want to use it to send/receive SMS messages...

Comment: are you running it with sudo ?

Comment: yes, if i don't, it says, that he has no access to /dev/ttyAMA0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I needed to connect PWR on SIM900 to GPIO pin in raspberry. Now it works.

Comment: It is unclear from your question which pin on the Pi you connected to; it would help others if you made that clear.

Comment: Any GPIO pin, not a special one. In my case GPIO 22 pin.